# Very simple C question using getchar() and putchar()

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

Hello I am teaching myself C and going through the K & R book and I am having some trouble (I am running OS X). This is from section 1.5.1 "File Copying" which is supposed to take a character as input, then output the character. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* --  Copy input to output -- */ 
int main(void)
{
int c;

c = getchar();

while ( c != EOF ) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar;
}


}
```

So, I think my problem is not with the code itself but with compling and running. First of all, when compiling I get the following errors

```
/Volumes/Goliath/Dropbox/C programs/prog1_5_1.c: In function ‘main’:
/Volumes/Goliath/Dropbox/C programs/prog1_5_1.c:12: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a        cast
/Volumes/Goliath/Dropbox/C programs/prog1_5_1.c:16: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Then when I run the output file (in terminal) it has a small space, then when I input a letter, say I type

a

then I hit Return

and I get a new line. If I then hit a new key, the screen starts going crazy with question marks all over the place.

I am not sure if I am making much sense but I am finding this an odd problem to have. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second assignment should be `c = getchar();`.  By leaving out the parentheses, you're assigning the address of the `getchar` function to `c`, which is very much not what you want.

Also, at the end of `main` you need the line `return 0;` or similar in order to get rid of the "control reaches end of non-void function" warning.

Comment: Or you can prototype main as being void: `void main(void)`

Comment: @Mel: That runs contrary to the C standard.  `main` should always return an `int`.

Comment: Yep, true and you get a compiler *warning* about, yet a valid program. When starting C, one should be made aware that there are many ways to screw up. :)

Answer (score 2):

you missed the () on getchar on line 12.  without parenthesis, "getchar" evaluates to the address of the function, which is why you get the pointer-cast-to-int warning

Answer (score 1):

You're missing parenthesis after the 2nd `getchar`.

This means you're assigning the location in memory of the method to the variable `c`, which causes an infinite loop as it's never equal to `EOF`.